# cannot run minimal example of powerdot

Tags: powerdot

I'm trying to compile this minimal example using the **powerdot** class but I don't see what's wrong. Here is a screenshot of the error. [image: screenshot of TeXShop Console]

```
%!TEX TS-program = latex
\documentclass[
  size=11pt,
  style=default,
  paper=screen,
%% Try me!
% orient=portrait,
 %mode=handout,  
   display=slidesnotes,
% blackslide,
nohandoutpagebreaks,
  fleqn
]{powerdot}


\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut} %
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amsthm,bbm}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\xx}{{\ensuremath{\mathbf{x}_{i^{*}}}}}
\newcommand{\rr}{{\ensuremath{\mathbf{R}_{g*}}}}
    

\title{{\Large here and there}}
\author{Me and Your}
\date{A.Y. 2020-2021\\[1cm]
\textcolor{ao(english)}{L. 9 ~~~~Clust}}



\pdsetup{
counters={theorem},
  logohook=t,
  logopos={.925\slidewidth,.985\slideheight},
  lf={ADM -- Cluster},
  rf={},
  trans=Replace,
  theslide=CA -- slide~\arabic{slide},
  list={itemsep=3pt,topsep=3pt,parsep=0pt}
}


\begin{document}


\maketitle

\begin{slide}[toc=]{Lect 9 \newline groups}
\small
\tableofcontents[content=all]
\end{slide}

\section[slide=false]{Intro}

\begin{slide}[toc=Ok]{So then}
write smth here....
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:** after fixing as suggested below, I get the following error

```
%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY

Error: /undefined in .setstrokeconstantalpha
Operand stack:
   397.485   238.492   0.0   238.492   1.0
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1974   1   3   %oparray_pop   1973   1   3   %oparray_pop   1961   1   3   %oparray_pop   1817   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:729/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:148/200(L)--   --dict:184/300(L)--   --dict:57/200(L)--   --dict:132/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 216788
GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
### FAILED to generate /tmp/altpdflatex.15339-1623244523/cluster2.pdf ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a certain point, the class has to execute (within an `\xdef`)

```
\expandafter\the\csname c@\pd@tempa\endcsname
```

where `\pd@tempa` runs over all counters to be protected (the predefined list has `table`, `figure`, `equation`, `footnote`, `mpfootnote`). By adding `counters=theorem` in your setup means that the class willy try to execute

```
\expandafter\the\csname c@theorem\endcsname
```

However, you haven't defined any `theorem` environment yet, and it is not predefined. This means that the counter `\c@theorem` does not exist, and the construction `\csname c@theorem\endcsname` expands to `\relax`; you arrive at `\the\relax`, and TeX complains:

```
! You can't use `\relax' after \the.
<recently read> \c@theorem
```

as you noted.

Long story short: define a `theorem` somewhere in your preamble.

```
\documentclass{powerdot}

\pdsetup{counters=theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} % <----

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}{Foo}
Bar.
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for you help! I'm getting another error now :-(. See the update section.

Comment: @utobi That's no TeX issue, but I've found something in the tug mailing list, starting from https://tug.org/pipermail/pstricks/2021/011259.html Maybe it helps.